# Kill a Thread in Python State Event

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, kill

I'm working with Python on my RPi an now I need help. The problem is that in the background of my program a thread is doing his work. This work is a State Event program made with definitions. However I need to kill this thread t in the else. I thought that it would work with stop, clear, or something like that but it doesn't work. If you need the full code just write it. This is the only thing in my code that doesn't work.

The RPi is connected with a board which includes 3 buttons and 6 LEDs. Each LED is a state. If the buttons are pressed correct (for example and), the state will switch. My board works without the RPi and then it's just a hardware solution. But for presentations the same has to be possible in software. And that's exactely the problem. If I switch from hardware in to software the thread is going to be active and if I switch back from software into hardware the thread is still in a state. Another switch into the software and the thread has a restart. But the old state (LED) wasn't deleted. So it looks like 2 states are active.

I just want to switch from hardware into software and back without any problems. The code you see is this switch as GUI

`def GUI_Function():`

```
def HW_SW_Mode():  

        t = threading.Thread(target=Main_Function)

        t.daemon = True

        if not Led_HW_SW_Mode.is_lit:                      
                Led_HW_SW_Mode.on()                     
                ledButton2["text"] = "Software aktiv"  
                t.start()

        else:                                        
                t._stop()
                RPi.GPIO.output(Led_List, RPi.GPIO.LOW)       
                Led_HW_SW_Mode.off()                    
                ledButton2["text"] = "Hardware aktiv"  

def close():                                           
        RPi.GPIO.cleanup()                             
        win.destroy()
```

- Main program works
- GPIO works
- Switch from HW to SW doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

1.) `t._stop()` will not work because it is being called in the main thread. The stop needs to be called from the thread itself. Here is an example of a thread that  can be stopped by another thread.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.running = False

    def run(self): // this is where the main_function definition goes.
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            print "I am still alive"
            time.sleep(10)

        print "I am stopping"

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
```

2.) `t._stop` will still not work with the above change also because it is called on a different object then the object that t.start is called on. Each time you call your function you create a NEW thread. You need to call stop on the same thread object you call stop on.

```
t = None // Place holder for thread. Find a way to make this not global if you can. 

def HW_SW_Mode():
    global t  // this means that assigning to t will affect the global t 
              // instead of pythons default to create a new t in the 
              // current scope which shadows the global t. Better to find 
              // a way to make it not global, but not a big deal if the code
              // is simple enough. 

    if not Led_HW_SW_Mode.is_lit:                      
            Led_HW_SW_Mode.on()                     
            ledButton2["text"] = "Software aktiv"  
            t = MyThread()
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
    else:                                        
            t.stop()
            RPi.GPIO.output(Led_List, RPi.GPIO.LOW)       
            Led_HW_SW_Mode.off()                    
            ledButton2["text"] = "Hardware aktiv"  
            print "Waiting for thread to return. If you get stuck"
            print " here something is wrong with the run loop in your"
            print " thread not returning when the running flag is set False"
            t.join()
```

Comment: Could you answer my question? With your code I received other problems...I need to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

So after put your code into my code, I've got a few more problems. To show you what the problem is, I post the first definition of my main function. Here we have your class MyThread and in this one I call my definition Configuration.

`class MyThread(threading.Thread):`

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.running = False

def run(self): # this is where the main_function definition goes.
    self.running = True
    while self.running:
        print ("I am still alive")
        Configuration()

    print ("I am stopping")

def stop(self):
    self.running = False
```

Here we actual have the first definition of my main function. You see that the else points back to Configuration. That should be a State-Event-Machine, so it has an endless loop. And from there I need a way out if I click the GUI button and put the leds off. With your additional Thread I'm stuck in the software mode and the GUI freezes if I want to go back to hardware mode. In the terminal is a endless loop of hello which is written in Configuration. How could I solve this? How do I get out of this and the GUI stop freezing.

`def Configuration():`

```
print("Hello")
Led_Configuration.on()                              
time.sleep(.1)
if button_Next.is_pressed:
        if (button_IN1.is_pressed and button_IN2.is_pressed):
            Led_Configuration.off()
            RPi.GPIO.output(Led_List, RPi.GPIO.LOW)             # Alle LEDs ausschalten
            time.sleep(.2)
            Wire_Library()
        else:
            Configuration()
else:
        Configuration()
```

And that's again the GUI with the Code from you including.

`def GUI_Function():`

```
t = None

def HW_SW_Mode():

        global t

        if not Led_HW_SW_Mode.is_lit:         
                Led_HW_SW_Mode.on()                 
                ledButton2["text"] = "Software aktiv"
                t = MyThread()
                t.daemon = True
                t.start()

        else:                         
                t.stop()
                RPi.GPIO.output(Led_List, RPi.GPIO.LOW)            
                Led_HW_SW_Mode.off()                
                ledButton2["text"] = "Hardware aktiv"
                t.join()
```

Thank you very much for you help. I would be very happy if this program finally work.